# SQL SERVER LIKE statement only works when inserting one Unicode character (doesn't work with multiple chars)

Tags: sql-server

I have some SQL query, like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE FIELD LIKE N'%ב%'
```

which works fine. but if I insert more characters, it doesn't return anything even it should (the field contains 'בוצע')

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE FIELD LIKE N'%בו%'
```

And ideas? thanks!

Comment: Your Hebrew text is not being encoded correctly in the T-SQL script. **Where** is this query being run? In SSMS? In a `.cs` file? Etc? Make sure **every** file you ever load and save is using UTF-8 (without a BOM) - unfortunately too many software programs still default to some ancient codepage or other encoding scheme today, ugh...

Comment: Does your Hebrew have diacritics such as `בֹּוִִֹצֵע`? Did you actually insert it correctly with `N` or an `nvarchar` parameter?

Comment: @Dai, it didn't work on a nodejs server, so I debugged it through SSMS, to get the same result. How come it works with a single letter if it isn't encoded correctrly?

Comment: @Charlieface, yes I made sure. I see the string correctly and it does contain what I'm querying for. (also note that it did work with a single character)

Comment: Please construct a [mcve] such as with https://dbfiddle.uk showing the problem (`CREATE TABLE` `INSERT` and `SELECT` statements)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an absolute *last-resort* option: if you need to insert Unicode text in a Unicode-unsafe end-to-end scenario (i.e. where *something* in-between your keyboard and the target database is mangling correct Unicode encoding, or using some other encoding) then you should always be able to fall-back to using `CONCAT( NCHAR(), ... )` to build a string using only [7-bit ASCII-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-bit_clean) T-SQL source...

You'd replace the literal Hebrew characters in the string-literal with [an `NCHAR()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/nchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) - this will work regardless of how your SQL is saved or encoded (don't forget RTL/LTR handling too...):

```sql
DECLARE @hebrewLikePattern nvarchar(50) = CONCAT( N'%', NCHAR( 1489 ), NCHAR( 1493 ), NCHAR( 1510 ), NCHAR( 1506 ), N'%' );

SELECT
    *
FROM
    tbl
WHERE
    someColumn LIKE @hebrewLikePattern;
```

---

(For some reason I can't seem to post Hebrew text to StackOverflow without RTL/LTR getting messed-up - so here's a screenshot of the char values I got using Linqpad):

[image]

Comment: This would be a very painful solution even if it works, because you'll need to add the `nchar()` functions in `ltr` as English but the word will need to be `rtl`, so will be very confusing, `ע` will need to be first `nchar()` and `ב` last `nchar()` while when thinking of the word you're looking for it's the opposite.

Comment: @Shmiel "This would be a very painful solution" - _indeed_ - what I meant was that `NCHAR()` can be used as a last-resort if there are end-to-end encoding issues that can't be easily fixed.  It's been many years since I last used - or worked-with - RTL strings or text so yeah, my answer's a bit of a mess, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following.

**SQL**

```
-- SQL Server 2017 and earlier
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, hebrew_col NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl (hebrew_col) VALUES
(N'שָׁלוֹם');

SELECT * FROM @tbl;

SELECT * FROM @tbl
WHERE hebrew_col LIKE N'%ל%';

-- SQL Server 2019 onwards
DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
    hebrew_col VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8);
INSERT INTO @tbl2 (hebrew_col) VALUES
(N'שָׁלוֹם');

SELECT * FROM @tbl2;

SELECT * FROM @tbl2
WHERE hebrew_col LIKE N'%ל%';
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8` instead of `Hebrew_CI_AS` ? (also, `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8` requires SQL Server 2019 or later with UTF-8 enabled, which is painful to set-up correctly IME.

Comment: My point was to show that a generic not explicitly Hebrew collation, but with UTF-8, supports Hebrew characters. Even with diacritics (nekudot). All that in MS SQL Server 2019.